# will cronjob having 2 triggers with different cron-expression will trigger twice if same condition satisfies both the triggers?

Tags: cron, sap-commerce-cloud

I have a cronjob which runs 2 days a week at 4:30 CET with help of trigger.

```
0 30 4 ? * MON,WED *
```

I want to it to also run in the 1st day of month. since in a cron expression days in a week and day of month we can't put it together.

So, if i add new trigger with cron expression of 1st day of the month with the same time 4:30 CET, it will trigger the cronjob twice because condition is satisfied in both the triggers?

```
0 30 4 1 * ? *
```

if yes then can anyone suggest any solution?

Comment: same cronjob can't be run at sametime ,OOB it checks if jobs is already running that 2nd instance will throw exception like cronjob is already running.

Answer (score 0):

If the cronJob is in running state then you cannot run it again until it finishes, but if you want to run it with different triggers, then you can create 2 different triggers.